# Django index error

Tags: django

Yesterday it worked fine when I ran the server but today I am getting this:

```
****Environment:
Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://192.168.2.206:8080/home/
Django Version: 1.1.1
Python Version: 2.6.5
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.markup',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.sites',
 'django.contrib.comments',
 'mysite.registration',
 'mysite.profiles',
 'mysite.epw',
 'mysite.remember_me',
 'mysite.avatar',
 'mysite.django_documents',
 'mysite.inlines',
 'mysite.blog',
 'mysite.forum',
 'tagging']
Installed Middleware:
('django.middleware.cache.UpdateCacheMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.cache.FetchFromCacheMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'mysite.remember_me.views.AutoLogout')
Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  92.                 response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/views/decorators/cache.py" in _wrapped_view_func
  44.         response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/utils/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  48.                 response = view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/karthik/Desktop/EPW_LOCAL/mysite/../mysite/remember_me/views.py" in remember_me_login
  81.     result_of_update, result_of_category, result_of_cover, result_of_latest, result_of_block, result_of_footer, result_of_research = common_blocks()
File "/home/karthik/Desktop/EPW_LOCAL/mysite/../mysite/epw/views.py" in common_blocks
  332.     result_of_update = display_updated_date()
File "/home/karthik/Desktop/EPW_LOCAL/mysite/../mysite/epw/views.py" in display_updated_date
  1357.     updated_obj = pdf_database.objects.filter(updated_date__gte = previous_datetime, updated_date__lte = cur_datetime).order_by("-updated_date")[0]
File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.6/django/db/models/query.py" in __getitem__
  159.             return list(qs)[0]
**Exception Type: IndexError at /home/
Exception Value: list index out of range******
```

Answer (score 0):

Your queryset has 0 results. specifically this one:

```
updated_obj = pdf_database.objects.filter(updated_date__gte = previous_datetime, updated_date__lte = cur_datetime).order_by("-updated_date")
```

Answer (score 0):

> yesterday its working fine when run server today i am getting like this

Add a new `pdf_database` object from the admin or console and this view should be back running fine like yesterday